# return an variable updated in a sub-function

Tags: javascript, callback

Please check the following code:

```
function loadCSV(fileInput) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(fileInput);
    var result = {};
    var file = {};
    var error = {};
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        var csv = evt.target.result;
        var data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
        file[fileInput.name] = data;
        result['file'] = file;
        console.log(result);
    }
    reader.onerror = function() {
        error = {
            'message': 'Unable to read ' + fileInput.name
        }
        result['error'] = error;
    }
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

The `result` within the `reader.onload` section is correct, but the `result` returned is empty. I know this is because I am updating the `result` in a sub-function `reader.onload` and I also know using callback for `loadCSV` is a solution to solve the problem. But I want to know whether there is any way that I can make `loadCSV` returning the updated `result`.

Thanks.

Comment: Look for the promise pattern, e.g., [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: The filereader API is asynchronous, your outer function returns before the callback is executed. You can't return from an asynchronous function. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: @FelixKling - That's a good thread.

Answer (score 1):

Any event handler attached to `FileReader.onload` is going to be an asynchronous function, which means it's done when it says it's done. If you want to do something with the result, you're going to have to do it inside your handler function.